# Unexpected token '>' on ajax promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My code make an ajax call and manage promises on the ajax function:

```
element.on("keypress", ".keyEvents", function(event) {
            if (event.which == 13) {
                // form the url and the json object                
                var putUrl = url.replace(idInUrl, originElement.attr(idAttr)); //replace idInUrl in url by id                
                var putObj = {};
                putObj[jsonAttr] = $(this).val();

                // AJAX query as a promise
                console.log(putUrl);
                return putAjax(putUrl, putObj).then(data => {
                    // DOM operation on success
                }, error => {
                    // DOM operation on error
                });

            } else if (event.which == 27) {
                // if Esc is pressed

                // replace whith origin element
                $(this).replaceWith(originElement);

            };
        });
```

The ajax function is defined in the module:

```
function putAjax(putUrl, putObj) {
        return $.ajax({
            method: "PUT",
            url: putUrl,
            data: JSON.stringify(putObj),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        });
    };
```

But I have an exception: `Unexpected token '>'` on the line where `return putAjax(...).then` call.

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe your browser doesn't have support for ES6 arrow functions. Does it work if you do it like this instead? 
return putAjax(putUrl, putObj).then(function(data) {
                    // DOM operation on success
                }, function(error) {
                    // DOM operation on error
                });

Comment: Which browser are you testing with? It's choking on the arrow function which isn't fully supported everywhere.

Comment: Safari Version 9.1.3

Comment: That's it, Safari doesn't support the arrow function, Chrome does, I've changed to the regular anonymous function declaration. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned in your comment that you're using Safari 9.1.3.

This [does not support arrow functions](http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions), so the browser is seeing the `=` and is expecting an expression on the right hand side. `>` is not an expression, so it's throwing the error.

You can fix the error by using a ES6 transpiler such as [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), or by using the older function style:

```
// ES6 style
(x) => x * 2;

// equivalent old style
function(x) { return x * 2; }
```

In your code:

```
element.on("keypress", ".keyEvents", function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        // form the url and the json object                
        var putUrl = url.replace(idInUrl, originElement.attr(idAttr)); //replace idInUrl in url by id                
        var putObj = {};
        putObj[jsonAttr] = $(this).val();

         // AJAX query as a promise
        console.log(putUrl);
        return putAjax(putUrl, putObj).then(function(data) {
            // DOM operation on success
        },
        function (error) {
            // DOM operation on error
        });

    } else if (event.which == 27) {
        // if Esc is pressed

        // replace whith origin element
        $(this).replaceWith(originElement);

    };
});
```